# Error calling base constructor (PrismApplication constructor) in App.xaml.cs

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'd appreciate some help on the following..

I have started a Xamarin Forms application using Prism Forms.

I created the project in Visual Studio (Windows) using the Template Pack.

The project builds OK but when I try to run it in the Simulator on my Mac I get an error on the call to the base constructor of the PrismApplication class as soon as the application starts. See error message and stack trace below. Thanks in advance.

**Package Versions**

- Prism.Ninject.Forms Version: 7.0.0.168-pre (Also tried same version of Unity.Forms)
- Xamarin.Forms Version: 2.4.0.282

**Error Message**: Operation is not supported on this platform

**Source**: System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight

**Stack Trace:**

at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor (System.String name, System.Type returnType, System.Type[] parameterTypes, System.Boolean restrictedSkipVisibility) [0x00006] in <896ad3a163a543758d64d3128b003bfb>:0 
  at Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.Create (System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor) [0x00005] in :0 
  at Ninject.Planning.Strategies.ConstructorReflectionStrategy.Execute (Ninject.Planning.IPlan plan) [0x0005c] in :0 
  at Ninject.Planning.Planner+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0 (Ninject.Planning.Strategies.IPlanningStrategy s) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] series, System.Action`1[T] action) [0x00010] in :0 
  at Ninject.Planning.Planner.CreateNewPlan (System.Type type) [0x00053] in :0 
  at Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan (System.Type type) [0x00026] in :0 
  at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create (Ninject.Activation.IContext context) [0x00053] in :0 
  at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal (System.Object scope) [0x00034] in :0 
  at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve () [0x00073] in :0 
  at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve (Ninject.Activation.IRequest request, System.Boolean handleMissingBindings) [0x00144] in :0 
  at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve (Ninject.Activation.IRequest request) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator (Ninject.Syntax.IResolutionRoot root, System.Type service, System.Func`2[T,TResult] constraint, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters, System.Boolean isOptional, System.Boolean isUnique) [0x0002f] in :0 
  at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T] (Ninject.Syntax.IResolutionRoot root, System.String name, Ninject.Parameters.IParameter[] parameters) [0x0000d] in :0 
  at Prism.Ninject.PrismApplication.CreateNavigationService () [0x00010] in :0 
  at Prism.PrismApplicationBase`1[T].Initialize () [0x0004d] in <ec44a08008f44d76a60fa1415f8ba03b>:0 
  at Prism.PrismApplicationBase`1[T].InitializeInternal () [0x00006] in :0 
  at Prism.PrismApplicationBase`1[T]..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer`1[T] initializer) [0x00031] in :0 
  at Prism.Ninject.PrismApplication.get_Logger () [0x00000] in :0 
  at MyProject.App..ctor (Prism.Ninject.IPlatformInitializer initializer) [0x00000] in /Users/Tomas/Projects/MyProject/MyProject/MyProject/App.xaml.cs:23 
  at MyProject.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00007] in /Users/Tomas/Projects/MyProject/MyProject/MyProject.iOS/AppDelegate.cs:24 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5489/c4240f3f/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5489/c4240f3f/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at MyProject.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/Tomas/Projects/MyProject/MyProject/MyProject.iOS/Main.cs:17

Comment: Can you please clarify are you using Prism.Unity.Forms or Prism.Ninject.Forms?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I should clarify. I initially got the error while using Ninject.Forms. I subsequently changed to Unity.Forms but received the same error. I'll update my question to clear any confusion.

Comment: Hi Dan. Have you or the team confirmed whether or not there is an issue here or is it more likely my setup? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot duplicate your issue. I do see another issue with Ninject. I would suggest for now using a container other than Ninject and cleaning/deleting your output (obj/bin) folders.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Dan. I have decided I might use DryIoc as recommended by you in another post here on StackOverflow. I might first try creating a new project from scratch using the Prism Templates and see if I have similar issues. Thanks for the response - and aren't the Prism Team supposed to be on holidays! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am unsure what was causing the exception you noted here, this did lead to the discovery of a number of issues in Prism 7 preview 5 for Prism.Ninject.Forms, specifically revolving around the ContainerExtension. The issues have now been fixed and are available starting in version 7.0.0.340-ci on MyGet.